# why XML design (textviews) not set full top edge, right edge, and left edge- Android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Here in above screen shot it just looking fine and full screen only on my Eclips(Graphic Layout), but when i run it on my real device , then it show padding from top Right and Left as below screenshot. i just want it should same display on my real device as display above in (Graphic layout)
grey background have more padding so the text doesn't site right up to the edge.

[image]

Above is a screenshot. Below is my xml code. You can see in screenshot that the xml design is not showing as fullscreen. I want to show fullscreen all my items What am I missing?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:weightSum="4"
tools:context="selection.detail.Selection_datail_adapter" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#B2B2B2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_bettypeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/str_bettype"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_betTypeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailCourseID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/str_detail_course"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_courseID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailtimeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/str_detail_time"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_timeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_stackID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!--  android:autoLink="web"-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailurlID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Best Odds Available At"
            android:textColor="#0733F5" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/str_detail_horse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail_horseID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_total_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/str_detail_odds" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail_fractionID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_proofinglink_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/str_detail_decimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail_decimalID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Tell me what I am missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing padding/margins in one of the containers: ListView/RecyclerView, fragment layout, activity layout.

Comment: yes , your answer is right :) i Got solution from your answer thanks a lot @Sergey Glotov